# Can I access the failover server on AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a working proof-of-concept in AWS for our web application which suddenly needs to scale out very quickly.  Currently it is hosted on a local VMware server and we are migrating to AWS.

I am working on configuring an MS SQL Server instance on AWS RDS with multi-AZ mirroring enabled.  We would like to have a set-up that allows us to read from the replica and write to the primary.  Is there a way to access the mirrored failover/replica server or will I need to find another solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no you cannot.

[From the Amazon RDS FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/)

> Q: When running my DB Instance as a Multi-AZ deployment, can I use the
>   standby for read or write operations?
>
> No, the standby replica cannot serve read requests. Multi-AZ
>   deployments are designed to provide enhanced database availability and
>   durability, rather than read scaling benefits. As such, the feature
>   uses synchronous replication between primary and standby. Our
>   implementation makes sure the primary and the standby are constantly
>   in sync, but precludes using the standby for read or write operations.
>   If you are interested in a read scaling solution, please see the FAQs
>   on Read Replicas.

AWS relies on database mirroring to support mutli-AZ deployments of Microsoft SQL Server and consequently, read replicas are also not supported.

I'd recommend EC2 instances, AlwaysOn Availability Groups and Active Secondaries.

There is a pretty solid [whitepaper](https://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/whitepapers/alwayson/) available for configuring failover clustering and AlwaysOn Availability Groups on AWS.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access the multi-AZ server other then the primary Amazon gives you. What you can do is create N number of slave servers and setup your reads off those

Comment: Considering that AWS' SQL Server implementation doesn't support SQL Server replication, I'm not sure how that is a solution.  Can you elaborate on your answer?  Thanks.